# Custom sidebar VF styles not affecting header

Tags: visualforce

I've got the following code in a custom sidebar VF component and it's applied to all Homepage layouts.  But the style isn't affecting the header.  If I take the same code and display it in a standard VF page it does affect the header.  How can I get this to work from the sidebar?

```
<apex:page >
<style>.brandZeronaryFgr{display: none !important;}< /style>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: What elements on the page have the class `brandZeronaryFgr` on them? Where are they located? (directly on the page, in an iframe, etc.)

Comment: The brandZeronaryFgr class is for the default 'Help & Training' link in the header.

Answer (score 2):

Everything inside of the sidebar is hosted inside of an iFrame specifically to avoid interactions between Javascript/CSS there and the overall UI. Salesforce use this mechanism for security reasons so I don't think you're going to find a way around it!